# wxWidgets and Visual Studio Linker Error When Compiling with a Static Library

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, linker, wxwidgets

I'm getting this linker error when compiling wxWidgets in Visual Studio 2010.

```
msvcrt.lib(wcrtexew.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16
```

Now here's the problem.  The entry point for wxWidgets is this macro:

```
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

Which means I don't use wWinMain() as an entry.

I've tried disabling the entry point when I compile (/NOENTRY), but no dice.  Nothing seems to work because if I define wWinMain(), then wxWidgets won't start because the entry is IMPLEMENT_APP.

I only receive this error when I compile as static.  If I don't compile as static I'll have to supply the DLLs: msvcp100d.dll and msvcr100d.dll on Windows Server 2008 (and maybe more DLLs on older versions of Windows that don't have the library installed).

Now I understand I am linking again the debug library, but it shouldn't matter if I link again the release because I should receive the same error (unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First compile wxWidgets' Library (wxWidgets\build\msw) all with the same settings you have in your project.  So I enable "/MT", "Use MFC in a Static Library", and output the projects as "Release".  Same exact settings on my wxWidgets' application I coded.

Now Comment out:

```
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

And use this for your entry point:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    char *buf;

    buf = new char[wcslen(lpCmdLine) + 1];

    wcstombs(buf, lpCmdLine, wcslen(lpCmdLine) +1);

    wxApp::SetInstance( new MyApp());

    wxEntry(hInstance, prevInstance, buf, nShowCmd);

    wxEntryCleanup();
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution, it's a workaround for a problem you still haven't really found. Of course using IMPLEMENT_APP() should work just fine, this is what it is for -- so something is wrong with your build settings.

Answer (score 1):

When you link to static libraries you have to ensure that the libraries were built with the EXACT SAME parameters as you used to build the application code.

So: go through all the compiler options for the library build and the application build and ensure that they match.  Also, make sure that the application build is linking to the static libraries there were built using the configuration you have matched.

It is a pain!  You have to decide wether you want to deal with this problem, or the problem of installing the correct DLLs on the target machine.  Either way, you have to solve configuration management problems.

In your particular problem, I see the linker is looking for _wWinMain@16 which suggests that you have build your application code with unicode switched on, but are linking to a non unicode static library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

`IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)`

In a .cpp file? It is typically in the accompanying file to where `IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)` is located.

I am using wxWidgets as a static library and that is what I do to compile.

Comment: Yes.  Could you upload a sample project?  So I can see the if my VS settings are correct and code.

Comment: There are plenty of projects in the samples folder that comes with wxWidgets. They are also using static libraries, have you taken a look in there?

Comment: No, I will now.  Good thinking.

Comment: Sadly they are using eVC 3/4 Workspace (.vcw) and that isn't even compatible with Visual Studio.  Can't use to check my VS settings.

Comment: The samples directory should come with .sln projects (I believe they are VS2008 projects, but if you open them you can convert them to VS2010 projects, which is what I do). What version of wxWidgets do you have?

Comment: From what I recall, there should be a vs projects and .sln projects. Do you not see any? There should be a `samples.sln`.

Comment: Yea, I found it.  Kinda odd to me that I have to convert all the projects to VS 2010, instead of converting which ones I wanted.  I'll let you know soon-ish any issues after analyzing these samples.

Comment: I'm trying to compile as Unicode Release with "Use MFC in a Static Library" + "/MT" and getting a ton of linker errors :(.  I'm gonna dabble with the project until I get bored.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I changed my project's character set to unicode. My project uses multi-threaded Debug DLL (`/MDd`). Above workaround worked for me, too, but I wanted to find out what was actually causing the problem and use `IMPLEMENT_APP`.

After I changed "Use of MFC" to "Use Standard Windows Libraries" I was able to successfully build the project.